# Is "unsigned int" considered to be a data type?

Tags: c++, c

If I have:

```
unsigned int i;
```

Is `unsigned int` considered to be a data type by itself just like an `int` or a `float` is a data type? or we just say that `int` is the data type while the `unsigned` is just modifying the way the data type works?

Comment: `std::cout << std::is_same<int, unsigned int>::value << "\n"; // false` [See on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7219ebb04ac21b61)

Comment: Yes; `unsigned int` is a separate data type from `int`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Is "int" just an alias for "signed int"?

Comment: What is the programming problem you are having where this distinction is important?

Comment: `signed` was a very late addition to C, primarily for `signed char` as a counter to `unsigned char` (which had been around for a while), to deal with the indeterminacy about whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned, and to ensure you could get signed bytes even when plain `char` was unsigned.  AFAIK, `signed int` is just an alias for `int`, and `signed long` is an alias for `long`, but `signed char` is not an alias for `char`.

Comment: Also, `signed int` is useful in specifying bit-fields: again, it is implementation defined whether a plain `int` bit-field is signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ standard §3.9.1, paragraphs 2-3: (C is similar)

> 2. There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”…
> 3. For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) standard unsigned integer type: “unsigned char”, “unsigned short int”, “unsigned int”, “unsigned long int”, and “unsigned long long int”…

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the ANSI C standard when you cite that reference?  Others might not know!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From C11 6.2.5 Types, paragraph 6:

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword unsigned) that uses the same amount of storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements. The type _Bool and the unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer types are the standard unsigned integer types. The unsigned integer types that correspond to the extended signed integer types are the extended unsigned integer types. The standard and extended unsigned integer types are collectively called unsigned integer types.